# Rendering jsp value as part of html tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, portlet

The tag library is being imported :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://ajaxtags.org/tags/ajax" prefix="ajax"
%>
```

But the uri http://ajaxtags.org/tags/ajax does not appear to exist, perhaps this could be causing the issue ?

When I pass a parameter

```
<input type="hidden" name="myid" value="<%=myid%>" />

<td class="myclass" valign="top" width="50%">
       <li >
       <ajax:portlet
       source=""
       baseUrl=""
       parameters="myid={myid}"
       classNamePrefix=""
       title=""
       imageMaximize=""
       imageMinimize=""
       imageRefresh=""
       refreshPeriod="" />
       </li>
  </td>
```

myid will have value something like 2342S

But the value of myid is not being rendered, instead the String "{myid}" is being rendered.
How can I force the value "myid" to rendered, in this case 2342S ?

I have tried   `parameters="myid=${myid}"` and `parameters="myid=<%=myid%>"` but this does not any difference.

How can the myid parameter value be rendered within `parameters="myid={myid}"` ?

Comment: In JSP it's `${myid}`. How sure are you that there's a `myid` attribute on the request object?

Comment: No, the AjaxTags page does say the syntax is {myid} (http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/usage.html). Are you inside the form tag? Maybe add an id attribute on your field along with the name attribute

Comment: @JP Moresmau thank you, adding it as an id instead of name did the trick